# Show that $y(n)=n\log_2n$, $y(n)∈O(n^2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I want to know more about the $O$-Notation, but can't seem to grasp the idea of it. It essentially formalizes the notation that 2 functions "grow at the same rate" or "one function grows faster than the other". So if $f(n)=1000n^2$, $g(n)=n^3$. When $n>1000$ $f(n)<g(n)$ so we say that $f(n)=O(g)=O(n^3)$.

Now let's consider $h(n)=3n^4+5n^3+7\log_2n$ and $y(n)=n\log_2n$. How do I show that $h(n)=3n^4+5n^3+7\log_2n$ and $y(n)∈O(n^2)$.

Comment: In your last sentence you seem to be asking how to show $h$ is defined the way you chose to define it in the previous sentence.   This doesn't make sense.  Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $n \log_2 n = O(n^2)$, we want to show that there exists a constant $C$ such that, for $n$ sufficiently large (depending, at most, on $C$)
$$
| n \log_2 n | < C n^2.
$$
Noting that for $n>1$ we have $n \log_2 n >0$, we can dispense with the absolute values.

We can study the function 
$$
f(n) = \frac{n \log_2 n}{n^2} = \frac{\log_2 n}{n}.
$$
It is not hard to show that $f(n)<1$ for all $n\ge 1$ . Hence, we have that
$$
n \log_2 n < n^2$$
for $n>0$ and so $n \log_2 n = O(n^2)$.

Comment: But if $n<0$ doesn't $n\log_2(n)$ have a non-real answer?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.  It is now fixed.